# How to let chapters in thesis preamble start on odd and even pages?

Tags: chapters, koma-script, books

I am using documentclass scrbook to write my thesis. I think the class implies that each new chapter starts on an odd page, which is generally a good idea. However, I have some short unnumbered chapters in the preamble of my thesis (e.g. Abstract, Acknoledgments, Publications) and I would like to avoid a lot of blank space there.

Is it possible to let single chapters start directly on the next page, disregarding whether the next page is odd or even?

I really hope this question can be answered without a MWE :)

OK, here it comes:

```
   \documentclass[numbers=noenddot,headinclude=true,footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,BCOR=5mm,bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,a4paper,fontsize=12pt,english]{scrbook}     
    \begin{document}
    \chapter*{Abstract}
    Abstract.
    \chapter*{Acknowledgements}
    I would like to thank my supervisors.
    \chapter*{Papers}
    The thesis is based on the following papers.
    % Here will the thesis start:
    \chapter{Introduction}
    Introduction.
    \chapter{Chapter 2}
    Chapter two.
    \end{document}
```

The goal is to let the numbered chapters only start on odd pages, but to remove this restriction for the non-numbered chapters.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: And it would really be easier to answer with a MWE :)

Comment: I know it's probably not what you want to hear especially after @esdd 's kind efforts but, if I were your supervisor I'd advise you to just let it start a on new odd page. It's what readers anticipate subconsciously and any deviation from the norm jarrs slightly. And hey. If you can't take room to give these important  sections the space they deserve in your own thesis, when can you?

Comment: @marcellinus12 I think you might have misunderstood my goal. I want the chapters to start on odd pages, but not these small chapters in the frontmatter, that partly only consist of few lines.

Comment: I mean even those

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the KOMA-Script class `scrbook` you can use `\KOMAoptions{open=any}` and `\KOMAoptions{open=right}` to switch between this two modes.

```
\documentclass[
    numbers=noenddot,
    headinclude=true,footinclude=true,
    cleardoublepage=empty,% default
    BCOR=5mm,
    bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc,
    a4paper,% default
    fontsize=12pt,
    english,
    open=any% <- added
]{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\addchap*{Abstract}
Abstract.
\addchap*{Acknowledgements}
I would like to thank my supervisors.
\addchap*{Papers}
The thesis is based on the following papers.
%
% Here will the thesis start:
\KOMAoptions{open=right}% <- added
\chapter{Introduction}
Introduction.
\chapter{Chapter 2}
Chapter two.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Could you briefly explain the difference between \addchap and \chapter?

Comment: @Aki `\addchap` takes care of proper headers, see he KOMA-script dócumentation.